# Password protect posts in WordPress (one per user) then provide a link to each user's post that will automatically log them in

Tags: php, wordpress, passwords, password-protection, autologin

I have about 10.000 posts, and let's say 10.000 users who should be able to view their assigned post with an URL such as www.example.com/unique-nice-name-passphrase123 (not having to enter a password manually!)

I'm thinking the simplest solution would be to password protect each post with a unique password, then let users auto-"login" to the posts through providing the password in the URL. Is this possible somehow? Tried googling for relevant keywords and found little information about it

So: Is there any way to

- Programmatically bulk assign a passwords to a lot of posts
- Then check for correct password provided (i.e. using the GET variable in single.php)

Comment: I've tried to more clearly express the full intent of the question in the title.   I've also made the list formatting work correctly to make it easier to read and switched to using the approved example domain name.

Comment: This sounds like a really awkward way to use WordPress. You might be better off with something specifically designed for your use case.